# Eigenvalues of $AA^*$ and $A^*A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have seen a similar question to this answered on here before, but not exactly my question. Let $\sigma(A)$ denote the set of all eigenvalues of $A$ where we allow repeated entries (corresponding to multiplicities). Show that if $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, where $m \geq n$, then $\sigma(AA^*) = \sigma(A^*A) \cup \{0,\dots,0\}$ where the last set has $m-n$ zeroes.

The inclusion is straightforward for nonzero eigenvalues, but I am having trouble convincing myself for the zero eigenvalues. I was thinking of maybe diagonalizing both matrices and relating them somehow. However, this does not seem to work out. Perhaps Polar Factorization or SVD will help but I am not sure.

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the fact that, if $\lambda \neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^*$ and $A^*A$, then they have the same multiplicity (i.e. their eigenspaces have the same dimension)? If $E_\lambda$ and $F_\lambda$ are the eigenspaces of $A^*A$ and $AA^*$ respectively, then we can map $E_\lambda$ onto $F_\lambda$ by multiplying by $A$. This has an inverse corresponding to multiplying by $\frac{1}{\lambda}A^*$. This shows $E_\lambda$ and $F_\lambda$ are isomorphic, and hence have the same dimension.

Answer (score 1):

The zeros come precisely because $m = n + k$, for some $k \geq 0$.

Say $A = U \Sigma V^*$, where $\Sigma$ is $n \times n$, and $V^*V = I_n = U^* U$.
It follows that
$$
AA^* = U \Sigma^2 U^* \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
A^* A = V \Sigma^2 V^*,
$$
which proves the claim.